# How to reverse Line chart with fl_chart with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, fl-chart

I tried to sort list order by mileage(Km). It was successful.
Of cause chart is same direction. (20 -> 7 -> 13)

But I would like to reverse line chart.(13 -> 7 -> 20) order by date.
So I wrote following code.

```
    LineChartBarData(
          spots: spots.reversed.toList()
    )
```

But it does not work like following image.
In my debugger, the list is reversed for sure.

What is wrong with it?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: so u r saying when u use 
spots: spots
the graph u get is as shown in the image 
and when u use 
spots: spots.reversed.toList()
u get the same chart ?

Comment: `spots` is list of `FlSpot`.

Comment: sorry my comment was posted before i completed. 
can u check the ques again

Comment: In my debugger, the list is reversed for sure. But there is nothing change in Chart.

Comment: can u post the code where u r printing it on the debugger ?? i doubt if u r reversing the list twice. i.e no change in the list at all

Comment: I added pictures. I tried not to reversed. But same chart drawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I made it work.
I had tried to reverse `spots`.

However I change my mind to reverse only `ListView`.

```
ListView(
  children: fuelComponents.reversed.toList(),
),
```

[image]

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 6):

**My Answer**

> I think either this feature is not readily available in FlCharts yet
>   or not clearly documented.

**Two things to note:**

1. In any charting library you cannot reverse the plot by simply reversing the data. When you say reversed dart simply reverses the order the objects were added and not necessarily by any property of the objects in the list. Especially in your case `FlSpots`.
2. For a plot to be reversed it is necessary to flip the axis along which the plot is to be reversed. I assume in your case this is `X-axis`. If you check the flChart source [here](https://github.com/imaNNeoFighT/fl_chart/blob/master/lib/src/chart/line_chart/line_chart_data.dart#L114) there is some logic to calculate the minX and maxX which is then used for axis. This might do the trick I assumed and tested, ended up without axis labels.

Since you didn't share code, I am using one of the examples from their docs.
Check the following code and the results.

```dart
 LineChartData mainData() {
    return LineChartData(
      gridData: FlGridData(
        show: true,
        drawVerticalLine: true,
        getDrawingHorizontalLine: (value) {
          return FlLine(
            color: const Color(0xff37434d),
            strokeWidth: 1,
          );
        },
        getDrawingVerticalLine: (value) {
          return FlLine(
            color: const Color(0xff37434d),
            strokeWidth: 1,
          );
        },
      ),
      titlesData: FlTitlesData(
        show: true,
        bottomTitles: SideTitles(
          showTitles: true,
          reservedSize: 22,
          textStyle: const TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xff68737d),
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 16),

          margin: 8,
        ),
        leftTitles: SideTitles(
          showTitles: true,
          textStyle: const TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xff67727d),
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 15,
          ),
          getTitles: (value) {
            switch (value.toInt()) {
              case 1:
                return '10k';
              case 3:
                return '30k';
              case 5:
                return '50k';
            }
            return '';
          },
          reservedSize: 28,
          margin: 12,
        ),
      ),
      borderData: FlBorderData(
          show: true,
          border: Border.all(color: const Color(0xff37434d), width: 1)),
      minX: 11,
      maxX: 0,
      minY: 0,
      maxY: 6,
      lineBarsData: [
        LineChartBarData(
          spots: [
            FlSpot(0, 3),
            FlSpot(2.6, 2),
            FlSpot(4.9, 5),
            FlSpot(6.8, 3.1),
            FlSpot(8, 4),
            FlSpot(9.5, 3),
            FlSpot(11, 4),
          ],
          isCurved: true,
          barWidth: 5,
          isStrokeCapRound: true, 
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

**With `minX: 0` and `maxX:11`**

[image]

**With `minX: 11` and `maxX:0`**

> Here the axis is reversed, but the axis labels are missing. You will have to check this yourselves or raise an issue in their repo.

[image]

Comment: I just created a new issue in the FlChart repository: https://github.com/imaNNeoFighT/fl_chart/issues/809